# How to replace two nested for loops and if statement with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an if statement nested inside a for loop and both of these are nested inside another for loop. I'd like some suggestions if it can be replaced using the stream API and if it should be replaced or left as it is.

I've looked for solutions, but what I want seems more complicate as I need to modify a list based on id matching with another list.

```
for (User user : userList) {
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicleList) {
        if (user.getId().equals(vehicle.getUserID())) {
            user.addVehicleToList(vehicle);
        }
    }
}
```

To produce the same result using streams.

Comment: There is no need for nested loop, just 2 loops: 1) for mapping `userId`s to `Vehicle`s, 2) for collecting vehicles by users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Stream APIs, use the following code.

```
userList.forEach(user -> {
    vehicleList.stream()
        .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getUserID().equals(user.getId()))
        .forEach(user::addVehicleToList);
    });
```

Comment: now do this in parallel... `forEach` has very bad side-effects here; this is violating the specification

Comment: So, in this case, what would be an optimal solution? @Eugene

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like that

```
userList.forEach(
    user -> vehicleList.stream()
            .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getUserID().equals(user.getId()))
            .forEach(user::addVehicleToList)
);
```